# mongoose model method - require other models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 models ModelA and ModelB, both require the other one.
My problem is that if I put require on the top of my model when I try to do a simple query like `ModelB.find()` inside a method `ModelA.method.myMethod()` I get an error `find() is not a function`...

if I require my model inside the method:

```
ModelA.method.myMethod=function(){
var User = require('user');
}
```

all work fine...Why?I don't understand the reason....
For now I solve using `db.model('user')` but I want to understand the error.